# The System is shutting down unexpectly

Tags: 14.10, shutdown

The System is shutting down unexpectedly without any reason 
just always chrome is running with the terminal .
what must i do to prevent that ??

Ubuntu 14.10
laptop packard bell tn36
iam new at Linux.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean that it only shuts down when you run chrome from the terminal? I'm afraid the question isn't very clear - can you edit & fill it out a bit please? More detail on what it does & says is always useful.

Answer (score 0):

It may be shutting down to prevent overheating. Have you checked that the CPU temperature is not reaching dangerous levels?